# In MASM, swapping array elements in memory won't find the next value?

Tags: arrays, swap, masm

In MASM, I'm trying to sort an array but I run into a problem with comparing two adjacent elements if there is a "swap" that happens. The address will move 4 bytes to the next value, but when I try to place the value of that address into a register, it does nothing and I'm not sure why.

```
.686
.model flat
.code

_KasparovDecend PROC ; named _test because C automaticedxly prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp ; stack pointer to ebp
    sub esp, 8          ;8/4 = 2 local variables

    mov ebx, [ebp+8] ; address of first array element
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; number of elements in array
    xor edx, edx        ;make this 0
    xor eax, eax        ;make this 0, too

    push edi    ;save this
    push ebx    ;save this

    mov edi, ebx    ;make a copy of first element in array
    add edi, 4      ;move 4 to find second element

    mov edx, [ebx]  ;move first element into edx
    mov eax, [edi]  ;move second element into eax

    mov [ebp - 4], ecx      ;second ecx holder
    mov [ebp - 8], ecx      ;this will be used to store eax while eax is used as a counter temporarily

LoopTraverse:
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]    ;reset for more than 1 loop
    mov edi, ebx    ;make a copy of first element in array
    add edi, 4      ;move 4 to find second element

    mov edx, [ebx]  ;move first element into edx
    mov eax, [edi]  ;move second element into eax


    mov [ebp - 8], eax      ;store eax into [ebp - 8]
    mov eax, [ebp+12]
    dec ecx                     ;number of elements decremented to 0
    cmp ecx, 0
    je AllDone

    LoopSwap:
        dec eax                 ;decrement the counter
        mov [ebp - 4], eax      ;store decremented value into [ebp - 4] so it can be used next round

        cmp eax, 0              ;compares counter to number of elements -1 = number of comparisons to be made
        je LoopTraverse         ;jump to LoopTraverse

        mov eax, [ebp - 8]      ;return the value of eax
        cmp edx, eax            ;comparing the two values
        jge NextElements        ;if in order, just find next elements, else swap and find next elements


        mov eax, [edi]          ;SWAPS THE TWO ELEMENTS
        mov edx, [ebx]
        mov [edi], edx
        mov [ebx], eax


NextElements:
        add edi, 4              ;finds next 
        mov eax, [edi]

        add ebx, 4              ;finds second element
--------mov edx, [ebx]          ;THIS IS THE REGISTER THAT WON'T MOVE TO THE NEXT ELEMENT4
                                 ; IF A SWAP HAPPENS

        mov [ebp-8], eax        ;stores value into ebp-8
        mov eax, [ebp - 4]      ;returns counter into eax

        jmp LoopSwap


allDone:
    xor eax, eax
    pop ebx
    pop edi
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
_KasparovDecend ENDP

END
```

Comment: I don't think destroying the value in `ebx`, which is callee-save register, before pushing it is a good idea.

Comment: So, should I push `ebx` before `mov ebx, [ebp + 8]`?

Comment: Yes, in order to perserve its value.